# Atomic load, compare, modify, write - in C99 on ARM

Tags: c, arm, atomic, c99

I'm writing some embedded code, that can be interrupted by an external event (IRQ). Basically, what I need to do, is load a variable, compare it, load it, modify and store. However, if such interrupt occurs, this variable may be modified between my load/compare or load/modify operations. Thus, I need to make this operation atomic, to avoid unexpected behavior. Basically, my code is something like:

```
if(a>0) a--;
```

Now, I know, that C11 standard introduces atomic operations, and thet GCC has __atomic built-ins. However, this code must not be GCC-specific, and must adhere to C99 standard. How do I accomplish atomicity on ARM, without using GCC built-ins and C11 atomic operations?
Thanks

Comment: My guess would be either to use assembly, or to define macros that expand to the __atomic built-ins on GCC, or whatever else on other compilers.

Comment: Might I ask: why is C11 not an option? Forced to use an old toolchain or an unusual compiler?

Comment: Is there an instruction for "decrease if not zero" in the instruction set? If not, then some manner of mutex-like mechanism needs to be used. What is "ARM", more specifically? Cortex M? A?

Comment: @LHLaurini Yes.

Comment: @Lundin I couldn't find such an operation, although might have missed something. Cortex-M

Comment: Did you consider to disable interrupts temporarily?

Comment: Maybe [take a look at what GCC generates](https://godbolt.org/z/4axW36n8G)?

Comment: Assuming bare metal Cortex M, then you can do a "poor man's mutex" with a plain bit flag, as described here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102. Disabling the specific interrupt should be the last resort, and disabling _all_ interrupts is completely unacceptable.

Comment: I'd check `ldrex` and `strex`. Depending on the compiler you might need to use either assembly or intrinsics.

Comment: Can you just disable IRQ interrupts momentarily while you perform this operation?

Comment: Strictly speaking this is impossible; the C99 standard defines no such functionality.  So your code will have to contain something non-standard.  You'll have to decide whether that will be compiler builtins, or inline assembly, or a separate helper function written in pure assembly, or intrinsics from a library, or something else.  Once you decide that then people can help more specifically.  You should also say what version of the ARM architecture you are using, as different versions have different options for atomic instructions.